# PHP Replace number within string with max value

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace any number bigger than X with X in a string if it matches a pattern.

Example with X = 4000 and matching function(?)

I have a string like this:

```
 $code = "function(4500),function(3900),function2(12345)";
```

I want a string like this:

```
 $code = "function(4000),function(3900),function2(12345)";
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
preg_replace('function\(\d+>4000\)', '4000', $code)
```

Comment: Needing to use regex is a reasonable guess. Work through a regex tutorial (or look through a few examples), then try to write a regex to solve the problem, then come back and ask a specific question about your attempt if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `preg_replace_callback()` here:

```
$str = 'String "function(4500),function(3900),function(12345)"';
$x = 4000;

$str = preg_replace_callback('/[0-9]+/', function($match) use($x) {
    return min($match[0], $x);
}, $str);

echo $str;
```

Output:

```
String "function(4000),function(3900),function(4000)"
```

Comment: wasn't me ... but your function is exactly what i am looking at. thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Didn't thought that you down-voted. I guess it was the same user who down-voted your question. I've up-voted it. It's a good question and it was fun to solve.. :)